# jQuery Accordian not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi all I'm trying to create a accordion but I'm not sure if my html structure is wrong. Every time I press one of the panels I can't see it's content. I only notice that the next panel disappears. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function toggleDetailsPanel(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).next().removeClass("active");
    $(this).slideUp("slow");
    //fixme: hide the panel content
    $(this).next().hide();
  }

  //else it's open so show everything
  else {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).next().removeClass("active").slideToggle();
    //fixme: show the panel content
    $(this).next().show();
  }

}
```

```css
#details-info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  left: 0;
  background: grey;
  opacity: 0.4;
  border: 0 solid white;
  /*height should be dynamic based on accordian*/
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.accordian-btn {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #229AFC;
  border: 0 solid white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}

.accordian-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="details-info">
  <div class="accordian-btn">Description
    <p class="accordian-content">some random Description stuff up in here....</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordian-btn">Media
    <p class="accordian-content">some random Media stuff up in here....</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordian-btn">Venue
    <p class="accordian-content">some random Venue stuff up in here....</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordian-btn">Main Option
    <p class="accordian-content">some random Main Option stuff up in here....</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you calling toggleDetailsPanel()? You don't have $(document).ready(function($) {}); Check this for an example - http://uniondesign.ca/simple-accordion-without-jquery-ui/

Comment: You are not calling toggleDetailsPanel function!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordian-btn").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $(this).siblings('.accordian-btn').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#details-info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  left: 0;
  background: grey;
  opacity: 0.4;
  border: 0 solid white;
  /*height should be dynamic based on accordian*/
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.accordian-btn {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #229AFC;
  border: 0 solid white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}

.accordian-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.accordian-btn.active .accordian-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="details-info">
  <div class="accordian-btn">Description
    <p class="accordian-content">some random Description stuff up in here....</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordian-btn">Media
    <p class="accordian-content">some random Media stuff up in here....</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordian-btn">Venue
    <p class="accordian-content">some random Venue stuff up in here....</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordian-btn">Main Option
    <p class="accordian-content">some random Main Option stuff up in here....</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#details-info').find('.accordian-btn').on('click', function(){
      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    });
  });
```

```css
#details-info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%; left: 0;
  background: grey;
  opacity: 0.4;
  border: 0 solid white;
  /*height should be dynamic based on accordian*/
  width: 100%; height: auto;
}

.accordian-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #229AFC;
  border: 0 solid white;
  width: 100%; height: 75px;
}

.accordian-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}

.accordion-content.default {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

<body>
    <div id="details-info">
      <div class="accordian-btn">Description</div>
      <p class="accordian-content">some random Description stuff up in here....</p>

      <div class="accordian-btn">Media</div>
      <p class="accordian-content">some random Media stuff up in here....</p>

      <div class="accordian-btn">Venue</div>
      <p class="accordian-content">some random Venue stuff up in here....</p>

      <div class="accordian-btn">Main Option</div>
      <p class="accordian-content">some random Main Option stuff up in here....</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

A lot of this was referenced from here:

http://uniondesign.ca/simple-accordion-without-jquery-ui/

Comment: thanks Adpro. That definetly works but I need to understand why my code isn't working as well. Only way I can move forward and not get stuck next time as well. I have that site as well as others including: https://codepen.io/brenden/pen/Kwbpyj and https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_animate  \n if you know why my code wasn't working that would be helpful as I'd like to just have it work by adding an event listener.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned in my comment, you aren't calling your javascript method. I'm assuming you want an onclick? In my example, $('#details-info').find('.accordian-btn').click(function(){  is the onclick trigger.  Yours doesn't have one.  So your javascript will never run.

Comment: I cleaned up the code a bit. Just curious - are you new to JavaScript and JQuery?

Comment: Also, check out the order of your elements.  You're using .next() and you're expecting a child.  .next() is for siblings. In other words, your p element is within the div, but .next() will never get to it.  I still think your main issue is the fact that you're never triggering your toggleDetailsPanel function when a click happens.

Comment: thanks for responding. Not not new, just not really a front end person. I am calling the js function already. That hml is actually created dynamically in the dom via an event listener from another function. I think the problem has to do with the order of my elements. I want to get the child of the element. not it's sibling. I'll look online see if I can find that. thanks.

Comment: If it's being added dynamically then you need to make sure you're referencing a non-dynamically created element in jQuery. For example, you would do something like $('#non-dynamic').on('click', '.dynamic', function() {}); The reason is the DOM needs the object loaded for jQuery (or JavaScript) to know about one of the objects to attach the event handling to. Post the rest of your code and I can fix it up for you. That's probably a major issue of yours, as you can't just use $('.dynamic').on('click') for dynamic elements, if that makes sense.

Comment: adpro, can you email me? I checked out your profile but have no idea how to start a chat or dm with you. let me know if you do or we can come up with another solution. No stress either way.

Comment: I don't have your email address and I don't think there's any direct message support on here.  Are you able to update your question with the code you have?  That's probably the best way to ensure that others can comment if something is done best another way.

Comment: Did you end up getting this figured out?